# How to find attribute from HTML using XPATH

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have i am trying to retrieve text from html, so first load html

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc = web.Load(url);
```

Here the text to find is 0.802 and is directly in element and it works
for this html

```
<tr>
  <th>Reported-Normalized Volume Ratio</th>
  <td>0.802</td>
</tr>
```

The search string

```
var t5 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//th[.='Reported-Normalized Volume Ratio']/following-sibling::td").InnerText;
```

The value of t5 is 0.802 as expected

Now I need to find **data-price-btc="3535.5500891201248734"**

```
<tr>
 <th style="width: 300px;">Reported Trading Volume</th>
  <td><div data-target="price.price" data-price-btc="3535.5500891201248734"> 
   </div></td>
</tr>
```

Search string

```
var t1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//th[.='Reported Trading Volume']/following-sibling::td/div/@data-price-btc");
```

t1 is empty and I dont understand why

Comment: `//th[.='Reported Trading Volume']/following-sibling::td/div/@data-price-btc` should return required value.. What is current and desired output?

Comment: I think, with the HTML agility pack, you need to select the element node with XPath, then you can use the Attributes property to access element values. Direct XPath selection of attributes as nodes is not supported.

Comment: See https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/541953/selecting-attribute-values-with-html-agility-pack

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks man, I just realized that, Many thanks you saved my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem  is that with HTML Agility Pack
direct selection of attributes is not supported

https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/541953/selecting-attribute-values-with-html-agility-pack